# Function of 30 Ω resistor wired in parallel across the field coils of a vintage 12 V generator

Tags: resistors, generator

What function is served by the 30 Ω resistor wired in parallel to field coils (qty. 4 with a total resistance value of 5.8 Ω) in a vintage 12 V generator?

The 30 Ω resistor is in the form of insulated resistor wire (1 Ω per foot x 30') that is wrapped around one of the field coils. It is in the diagram attached, but oddly not mentioned in the legend. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: generator diagram]

Comment: Some DC motors could include a heating coil (for cold temperatures.)  But permanently wired across the fields implies it is not this (or designed to operate in the arctic circle.)  Or a typo/error/misprint.

Answer (score 1):

Could be to reduce arcing. The regulator works by chopping the field coil current with a set of vibrating contacts, so the resistor across the coil absorbs some of the flyback voltage when the contacts open.

Comment: That’s what I thought at first but the usual way is by having a resistor across the the contacts which this also has. (Item 11)